# Indexing nvarchar(max) in a special way

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm storing json content in `nvarchar(max)` column. I also have the notion of `deleted` data for which I use special bit column `deleted`, now, instead of using additional column I could use nullable for `nvarchar(max)` but in that case I would loose the ability to index that field. And in that regard I have several questions:

- Is it possible to index `nvarchar(max)` field on the fact that it is nullable or not
- Is there any reason to index bit field in my case `deleted` is used in only one temporal query:

---

```
@from bigint = 0,
@till bigint = 8639999999999999 -- Max JavaScript unix timestamp in milliseconds

...

SELECT  item.Id,
        item.PreviousId,
        item.UUID,
        CASE
            WHEN @from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext
            THEN item.Json
            ELSE NULL
        END AS Json,
        item.TableName,
        item.PermissionId,
        item.UpdatedOnCurr

FROM Computed item
WHERE item.Deleted = 0 AND ( -- <------------- HERE IS DELETED
    (@from < item.UpdatedOnCurr AND item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @till AND @till < item.UpdatedOnNext)
    OR (item.UpdatedOnCurr <= @from AND @from < item.UpdatedOnNext AND item.UpdatedOnNext <= @till)
);
```

Comment: Generally indexing a binary column is not particularly useful (there are exceptions, particularly if the binary column is part of a clustered index).  In addition, SQL Server already has a `NULL` bit to represent nullability.

Comment: So in general case, when the column is not a part of clustered index, indexing is meaningful, right?

Comment: You cannot index any single column or set of columns that could potentially be larger than **900 bytes** - and a `nvarchar(max)` is definitely (potentially) a lot larger. You cannot index such a large blob column.